# JavaFx - Unexpected token LPAREN found

Tags: java, css, netbeans, javafx

I have a JavaFx project. Everything else seems o.k, except for the css, where I have some of the classes getting an error highlight, for example, in:

```
.min_max_close {
    -fx-padding: 0 12 0 12;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 0 0;
    -dean-lightnavy: derive(navy, 100%);
    -dean-navygrad: linear (0%,0%) to (100%,0%) stops (0%, -dean-lightnavy) **(**100%, navy);
    -fx-background-color: linear (0%,0%) to (0%,50%) stops (0%, derive(deepskyblue, 80%)) **(**30%, deepskyblue) reflect;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, gray, 32, 0.5, 0, 0);

    -fx-background-image: url("../MediaTools/Ports/16/clearsearch.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-size: 16 16;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, derive(gray, 50%) 32, 0.5, 0, 0);
}

.win_min {
    -fx-padding: 0 12 0 12;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 0 0;
    -dean-lightnavy: derive(navy, 100%);
    -dean-navygrad: linear (0%,0%) to (100%,0%) stops (0%, -dean-lightnavy) **(**100%, navy);
    -fx-background-color: linear (0%,0%) to (0%,50%) stops (0%, derive(deepskyblue, 80%)) **(**30%, deepskyblue) reflect;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, gray, 32, 0.5, 0, 0);

    -fx-background-image: url("../MediaTools/Ports/Tiny/shevron_l.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-size: 10 7;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, derive(gray, 50%) 32, 0.5, 0, 0);
}
```

the parts in bold above get an error highlight in red:

```
Unexpected token LPAREN found
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

That is in these areas:

```
**(**100%, navy) -> the (
**(**30%, deepskyblue) -> the (
```

The project compiles perfectly, but I was just curious on how to fix this, and most importantly, if this could get me in trouble in the future. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the old syntax for gradients (which was not valid css!) please use the new syntax as described at http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

The your gradient looks like:

```
-dean-navygrad: linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 100% 0%, -dean-lightnavy 0%, navy 100%)
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 0% 50%, reflect, derive(deepskyblue, 80%) 0%, deepskyblue, 30%);
```